# Using np.cov() on a centered matrix not equivalent to matrix multiplication between the array and its transpose

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, mnist

I'm trying to get the eigenvectors and values for the MNIST dataset.
I'm testing out a concept on the dataset so I can carry it to a different dataset

I have a matrix M where the rows are the images and the columns are the pixel values.
I'm trying to do the above in two ways (taken from https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf, chapter 10, section 1 and section 5):

M is of shape 500 rows x 784 columns

First, I'm using the following code:

```
  V = cov(M.T)
```

and then using:

```
  V2 = np.dot(matrix.T,matrix) / 783
```

According to numpy's guide on cov(), it seems like with one variable given I the results of both should be identical, but they're not. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html

sorry if the question is simple and there's an obvious answer

**EDIT:**
if I take the highest eigenvector of both methods and scale it so the lowest number is zero and the highest is 255, I get the same vector. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you need to normalize by 499, not 783.

Comment: @PaulPanzer That didn't do it :\ I've noticed that it seems like the image is mirrored on the vertical axis though...